# SQL Syntax Error, Help Wanted

Tags: mysql, syntax, mysqlimport

I don't have much knowledge in this realm of SQL, so if someone could point out my syntax mistake here, I'd be greatly appreciative. Trying to import a large product datafeed.

```
mysqlimport  --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=,
--columns='SKU,Manufacturer Id,Brand Name,Product Name,Long Description,Category,SubCategory,Product Group,Thumb URL,Image URL,Buy Link,Keywords,Reviews,Retail Price,Sale Price,Brand Page Link,Brand Logo Image,Product Page View Tracking,Variants XML,Product Content Widget,Google Categorization' --local -u root -p
Database C:\data.csv
```

Comment: What is the error you get? have you tried without the apostrophes  in "--columns"? do you have a password for root?

Comment: No root pass, it's a local development environment. Did try with and without apostraphes. I am currently getting:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=','
--columns='SKU,Manufact' at line 1

Comment: the space in the column names might be an issue, try to see if it works with no spaces, or - try enclosing them with ' or `.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're executing above mysqlimport command from query browser or mysql command prompt.

That's why you're getting the error  'mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1....'. In mysql query content, above command is invalid.

To make this command work, open command prompt of windows or linux and fire above command. Make sure that you're in mysql server's bin directory while firing command.